# InDesign, IDML, XSLT: messed up xml output w/o obvious pattern

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I have an InDesign workflow where I export an tri-monthly updated document to IDML and then run some rather complex XSLT transformations to produce an XML output.

I **did not** change anything in my XSLT and the last time my XML was fine. Now the XML output I got is rather fragmented. Tags got randomly deleted, following no obvious pattern.

I tried everything from debugging my XSLT to applying new paragraph styles in InDesign to deleting "suspicious" characters like fixed whitespaces etc.

No luck.

Answer (score 0):

After literally hours I found this simple fix:

For each part of my XML that is corrupted, create a completely **new** text frame in InDesign. Then copy & paste the content from the old one into it. The IDML export and XSLT transformation worked again as expected (in my case).

I suppose something went wrong "under the hood" when I placed the new content in InDesign in the first place. Maybe a corrupted word document or such.